# Cannot delete folder on Synology NAS?

Tags: permissions, acl, delete, nas, synology

I logged in as root and tried to recursively delete the folder `/volume2/Name` using `rm -rf`

It started and deleted all the files/directories inside this folder `Name`, but it cannot remove the folder itself even though I am root:

```
rm: cannot remove 'Name’: Operation not permitted
```

The command `ls -l` list the permissions for this folder as:

```
d---------+ 1 root root
```

Synology has a special tool called `synoacltool` for these ACL permissions, but I don't know to use it.

So what do I need to do in order to be able to remove this (empty) folder?

Comment: `synoacltool --help` shows usage information - do you need more?

Comment: @Panki Yes, I have no clue what to do. I used it with the 'get' parameter to view the current permissions and that listed root as the owner. So changing the owner seems unnecessary and I dont know what else to change.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getfacl <dir>` to find out what the ACL is. Then look at the man page for `setfacl`. It should be `setfacl -b <dir>` which removes all extended ACL's.

Comment: I get 'command not found' when I run 'getfacl'. The system is a Synology NAS so that might be the reason?

Comment: You'll have to find and install whatever package for your distro has them. On opensuse it's `acl` funnily enough!

Comment: If you cannot install software on the nas, you may be able to mount it locally and use the tools there.

Comment: Synology uses a heavily modified and stripped version of Debian according to all sources. I found out that I must use 'synoacltool' instead of 'setacl' but I have no clue how to use it.

Comment: A search will help you, it also provides it's own help. Please read it and try.